# Install pandas on different python versions on same computer(Windows 10)

Tags: python, pandas

I recently installed a newer version of python version 3.10.8. I still have the old version running version 3.9.9.
I would like to install pandas on the new python installation using pip install pandas command. I don't know how to specify in the terminal so that it installs on the python 3.10.8 version installation.

Comment: Navigate  to the `Python310\Scripts` folder. That contains the version of `pip` that will install to that installation. When you just type `pip` in another folder you get whatever version is first on the path. To find out what version that installs to, do `pip --version`.

Comment: Somewhere in the installation directory of each Python should be a "pip.exe". If you run the one from the desired Python installation it should install to the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments above were useful. I will explain how i resolved it in case someone else has a similar issue.

There was no installation folder for the python 3.10.8 in the programs folder, i want to believe it was because of the installed 3.9.9 version which had a folder Python39 in the default installation location.

So I uninstalled and reinstalled the newer version (3.10.8) to a custom location/folder. I opened the Python\Scripts folder of the new installation in the command line. I was able to install pandas with

`pip install pandas`